# R: how to combine cell's value from different row into one cell

Tags: r

I am currently working with a data set has this feature:

[image]

however what I want it to be like is:

30 | 2,5,3

Anyone know how to do it ?

Comment: So your wanted output is string "30 | 2,5,3"?

Comment: `dplyr::group_by` and `dplyr::summarise` are your friends here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `aggregate()` with `paste()`.

```
df <- data.frame(x = rep(30, 3), y = c(2,5,3))
> df
   x y
1 30 2
2 30 5
3 30 3

> aggregate(y ~ x, data = df, paste, collapse = ",")
   x     y
1 30 2,5,3
```

Comment: Exactly what I want!!! Easy and Sufficient! I also wonder what type of "2,5,3" is now?

Comment: The class should now be `character`. Because of the comma, any kind of `numeric` class is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
my_df <- data_frame(A = 30, B = c(2, 5, 3))
my_transformed_df <- my_df %>%
    group_by(A) %>%
    summarise(B = paste(B, collapse = ", "))
```